# Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings - What just happen?

Tags: php, timezone

> Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/folder/script/controllers/AC.php on line 342

and at the script

```
return date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $tm);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the warning give an answer very clear:

> [...]please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/folder/script/controllers/AC.php on line 342

So, for examle, you can add next code to your php script (somewhere before the line 342):

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
   date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

More about (you have also some examples there):

- http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
- http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date-default-timezone-get.php